# String interpolation in multi-line Ruby string yields different result than same string on one line

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I just found a strange behavior with ruby's string interpolation where it makes
a difference if I use a multi-line string or not:

```
rescue StandardError => e
  msg = 'Some long error message without interpolation '\
        "#{symbol.inspect}: #{e.message}."
  Rails.logger.error msg
  raise e.exception(msg)
end
```

I broke the string for `msg` into two lines and put the first part in single
quotes because there was nothing to interpolate. Rubocop is happy then.

The logging statement logs the message with the correct values for `symbol`:

```
11:06:57 web.1        | Some long error message without interpolation "VALOFSYMBOL": ERRORMSG
```

But, when the exception that is raised after that, carrying the same message, is
finally printed (in resque failure log and airbrake), a *different value* (which
the variable had some time before) for `symbol` is printed:

```
Some long error message without interpolation "COMPLETEYDIFFERENT": ERRORMSG
```

Unfortunately I can't give a complete working example because there are some
application layers involved, I'm just hoping that there might be somebody who
can point me in the right direction. How could this happen? My understanding was
that the interpolation happens at the time the string is assigned to `msg`, but
that seems not to be the case.

Changing the code to a one line string fixes the issue, and the string is
printed as expected in both places:

```
  msg = "Some long error message without interpolation #{symbol.inspect}: #{e.message}."
```

Comment: don't know why without testing but I do my interterpellation of multiline string with the %Q followed by the delimiter, only probem there is the left indentation that is takin inside the string

Comment: I wanted proper indentation and no extra spaces, but couldn't use the new heredoc syntax of Ruby 2.3 `<<~`. So this was the only option left.

Comment: Strange indeed, because Ruby's parser produces identical results for both string variants. Without a reproducible example however, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Yes, makes sense to close it. Maybe it was a coincidence which caused this. I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something about the multi-line string syntax.